In Excel, what function can I use to find certain instances in a column of data?
Is there a function I can use that will search the contents of a column and either let me jump to each cell that contains a value more than a certain constant or give me a list of all cell addresses for cells containing a value more than a constant I have specified.
I have a column with values of the elapsed time between cells. I want Excel to give me a way of jumping to each cell in this column that has an elapsed time of more than time minutes. I tried using conditional formatting which works but this data set is too large and it wouldn't be an efficient use of time for me to scroll through the whole sheet looking for cells highlighted a certain way. I tried just using Ctrl + F to search but I don't think it will will work cause I don't know of a way to confine its search to this column of elapsed time or how I tell it to only show me cells with a value of more than 10 minutes.

Have you tried using the FILTER() function? And if you need the cell addresses then use the ADDRESS() function as array for FILTER() function and the elapsed time column as include to check if its more than 10 minutes. A screenshot or mock up sample data, might help here as well.

Why not use AUTOFILTER on the ribbonDATA tab?
